# DD and DU anomalys in function

Tags: java, pmd

I recently started using PMD to keep my code clean and it's been going well, but I've run into a few problems in the following function.

```
private final void readFile() throws Exception{
    code.clear();
    imports.clear();

    //DD anomaly
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try{
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;
        //DU anomaly 
        boolean code_started = false;
        //DU anomaly
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            if(code_started)    code.add(line);
            else{
                if(lineIsImport(line))
                    imports.add(line);
                else if(lineIsClassDeclaretion(line)){
                    code_started = true;
                    code.add(line);                     
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fn_ex){
        throw new Exception("File not found!");
    }
    catch(IOException io_ex){
        throw new Exception("Failed to read file: " + file.getName() + "!");
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(bufferedReader != null)  
                bufferedReader.close();
            if(fileReader != null)  
                fileReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException io_ex){
            throw new Exception("Failed to close reader");
        }           
    }
}
```

The first DD anomaly:

```
FileReader fileReader = null;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
```

If I don't set both to **null** the anomaly disappears, but I get an error in the finally block. I have no idea what the correct way of writing this should be.

Next is the DU anomaly:

```
boolean code_started = false;
```

If I don't set the variable the anomaly disappears, but again an error a few lines down.

The last is a DU anomaly:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
```

This anomaly is probably the same as the one above, but again I have no idea how to fix it.

I would be grateful if somebody could explain or show how to write this function in a manner that won't cause PMD to show the anomaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 7 or higher you can  try-with-resources. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Below is the example how you can use it.

Go Through: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for more info.

```
        File file = null;
        //Automatically closes resources try-with-resources block
        try( FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);){
            String line;
            boolean code_started = false;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
               //Code Goes Here
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fn_ex){
            throw new Exception("File not found!");
        }
        catch(IOException io_ex){
            throw new Exception("Failed to read file: " + file.getName() + "!");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved the first anomaly. It would be great to see how to solve it in older versions of java. Now I'm curious about the **boolean** variable, since that's the one that I don't understand at all.

Comment: what is exactly the anomaly saying for boolean?

Comment: I believe the tools keep on updating themselves as the newer versions of language are released. Was there an option when you were deploying your project in PMD to select the language version.

Comment: So if I told PMD that I'm using java 1.5 it wouldn't have flagged the FileReader and BufferedReader?     As for the DU anomaly - PMD only tells me that there is a DU anomaly and a line span from the current line to the end of the function,

Comment: For the Java version part, not sure....maybe(have never used PMD)...for the second part try changing the variable name, maybe it is casing issue....change the name to codeStarted or some other camel case...if it still fails then lets see what we can do...

Comment: Changing the name does nothing. As far as I can tell PMD doesn't like the fact that it is set to a value. If I write it as **boolean codeStarted;**, then PMD doesn't complain, but there is an error in the if statement.

Comment: Hi all, a PMD maintainer here. Unfortunately the DFA code is quite outdated  (ie: doesn't properly handle try-with-resources or for-each) and is therefore very unreliable. I'd personally not recommend using this rule at the moment if you don't want to deal with plenty of false positives. We have plans to revamp it at some point in the future, but right now we are working on more pressing issues. Feel free to submit any issues with false positives you may find: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Adata-flow

Comment: Nope moving i around does nothing except move the violation around. I'm starting to think that PMD is messing with me.   The only valid solution I can think of would be changing the function to just read in the file and then  leave the analysis to different functions. And to be honest, I don't find this approach very good.